# Using AA(A) batteries to power a 3.3V SoC

Tags: power-supply, batteries, 3.3v

I have a 3.3V SoC that could draw up to around 250mA - 300mA. Is it a good idea to power it using 2x AA(A) batteries? Is it supposed to be an unstable setup without decoupling capacitors?

Thanks

Comment: This questions needs more details. Most logic ICs including microcontrollers will not work correctly without decoupling caps.

Comment: @TurboJ It's a SoC, if that helps. How come logic ICs won't work correctly without decoupling caps?

Comment: Your board probably already has input smoothing caps and individual decoupling caps for any ic that needs them

Comment: Also, part number of the board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to one reply, decoupling caps are still needed regardless of the cleanliness of the power supply.  Digital logic draws most of its power consumption in millions/billions of short spikes per second, and the physics (inductance, mainly) of copper tracks and power-planes sees to it that this spiky power draw results in the power supply rail (Vcc, Vdd) going up & down at those millions/billions of spikes per second - not what you want for reliable running of whatever's going on in the chip.  It's the job of decoupling caps to supply this power to the chip, because they're deliberately places as close to the power supply pins as possible.
http://www.baldengineer.com/a-1uf-decoupling-capacitor-is-too-much.html

Answer (score 1):

Two AAs in series have about 3 V when full and 2.0 V when nearly empty, so I would use a step-up regulator to drive a "3V3 SoC".